# Starting Ubuntu14.04 after first installation it hang can't do anything

Tags: 14.04

Starting Ubuntu14.04 after first installation it hang can't do anything. asus m2n68-an plus motherboard, amd sempron 145 processor 1 gb ram and the onboard display chip is nvidia geforce 7025. how can i solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try the below commands,

```
sudo apt-get remove compiz-plugins

sudo apt-get remove compizconfig-settings-manager
```

After the above please reboot the machine and enter with safety recovery(by holding the shift key). Once you are done with this please select the additional drivers then check whether any drivers missed. If so install and login the system normally.

Hope this helps.